# Erro ao encontrar classe em aplicativo usando namespace

Tags: autoload, php

Estou implementando o `namespace` com `psr-4` em um pequeno aplicativo PHP e acontece que ele não está encontrando a classe `Mvc\Controller\MyController` e não percebo a causa

A estrutura de pastas é:

```
src/Controller

src/Model
```

A classe `src/Controller/MyController.php` é assim

```
namespace Mvc\Controller;

class MyController
{
    public function listUsers(){
        $model = new \Mvc\Model\MyModel();
        $result = $model->list();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

O `index.php`, no raiz é:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

print '<h1>Simplest PHP MVC</h1>';
print '<h3>Primeira fase - listar os usuários da tabela.</h3>';

use Mvc\Controller\MyController;
$con = new MyController();

print '<table>';
print '<tr><td><b>ID</td><td><b>Login</td><td><b>Senha</td></tr>';
foreach($con->listUsers() as $user){
    $login = $user->login;
    $id = $user->id;
    $senha = $user->senha;

    print "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$login</td><td>$senha</td>";
    print "<td><a href=\"view/delete.php?id=$id\">Delete</a></td>";
    print "<td><a href=\"view/edit.php?id=$id\">Edit</a></td></tr>";
}
print '</table>';
```

Estou recebendo o erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mvc\Controller\MyController' not found in /var/www/html/mvc/index.php on line 9

Se ajudar, segue o composer.json

```php
    "autoload":
    {
        "psr-4":
        {
            "Mvc\\" : "src/"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não cheguei a testar, mas tira essa barrinha do `src/` no `composer.json` e comenta aqui se deu resultado.

Comment: Verifique se o nome dos arquivos e pastas estão corretos, pode ter algum erro de digitação

Comment: Já tentou rodar um `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: LipESprY não alterou. Constamilan tá tudo certo. chavestop já fiz.

Answer (score 0):

Execute o comando composer dump-autoload